# How to Split and Rename files by Mail Merge Field

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, rename, batch-rename, mail-merge

I just finished a letter MAIL Merge on Word and would like to 1. Split the documents into separate WORD documents and 2. Save or Rename the files by 3 different mail merge fields.  I am not familiar with Macros or coding of any kind.  Is there an app or software that can easily  perform this task?

The only way I was able to do it was to split the merge into PDF's and rename the files manually.  This is a short term solution but will not help me when the letter goes through revisions, etc.

If there is a way to do this that is more complex, please give me very basic step by step directions.

Please help and thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this link for an add-in for Word:  http://www.gmayor.com/individual_merge_letters.htm

Comment: What does this do? How do you use it? [This is worth a read](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers). As is there's a good chance your question might be downvoted, flagged or deleted.

Comment: The link is actually quite useful - provides a solution and does work if you follow the instructions carefully.   I have used it to mailmerge and split invoices for emailing.